# connected null subsets of unit interval

Tags: real-analysis

Can there be a null subset of the unit interval $[0,1]$ which is not totally disconnected in the sense described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_disconnected_space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, since a connected subset of $R$ is an interval which has measure zero if and only if it is trivial.

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subset_of_Real_Numbers_is_Interval_iff_Connected